# Defining a curve() by a string

Tags: r, expression, curve

Good morning,

I'm stuck with type conversion between strings and expressions in R. I want to plot a curve (using the curve() function), with an equation defined by a string as follows:

```
curve(x^3)
## Ok, generates a curve as expected

qq<-"x^3"
curve(qq)
Error in UseMethod("qq") : 
no applicable method for 'qq' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

I can understand that, the first arg is supposed to be an expression.

```
curve(expr=expression(qq))
Error in curve(expr = expression(qq)) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

That I cannot understand: my understanding of expression(), from the man, is that
"... expression returns a vector of type "expression" containing its arguments (unevaluated)."

So, what must I do to plot a curve with an equation defined by the content of the string qq ?

Thanks

JF

Answer (score 5):

`curve` substitutes the expression in the very beginning:

```
substitute(expression(qq))
#expression(qq)
```

Form this it can't infer what it needs to:

```
all.vars(substitute(expression(qq)))
#[1] "qq"

all.vars(substitute(x^3))
#[1] "x"
```

I think you need the dreaded `eval(parse())`:

```
x <- 1:10
qq <- "x^3"
ff <- as.function(alist(x=, eval(parse(text=qq))))
curve(ff)
```

Edit (2020-09-21):

More than 6 years later, I'd do this differently. I don't like eval(parse())ing `qq` here because it creates an unnecessary security risk. Instead, I'd substitute it into the call and evaluate the call to `curve`.

```
qq <- parse(text = qq)[[1]]
eval(substitute(curve(qq), list(qq = qq)))
```

Comment: Indeed, you solution works (thanks !). I'm still not sure I do iunderstand why, though. Here you are converting the string to a function, and use the ability of curve() to deal with functions. Nothing wrong with that, but why cannot you generate an expression from the string qq and use it straight into curve() ? I do not mind so so much eval(parse()), but why does `curve(expr=eval(parse(text=qq)))`, or `curve(expr=parse(text=qq))` not work ?

Comment: Read the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: (+1) for understanding the `curve` documentation